# Custom Menu to access Custom Brushes, Scenes, Layouts, etc

Tags: python

I want to make some menus (that I can call with a shortcut) that will give me shortcuts to custom brushes, scenes, layouts, etc.

For example

Menu
Custom Brush 1
Custom Brush 2

or
Menu
Custom Scene 1
Custom Scene 2

or 
Menu
Custom Layout 1
Custom Layout 2
etc.

I have made some menus for operators and even to do things like switch render engines, but this is beyond my understanding of python scripting.  From what I have read this has something to do with variables.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: there is a template for pie menus Text Editor -> Templates -> Python -> Ui Pie Menu. Also see this video tutorial: https://vimeo.com/103321600 Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/q/9109/2271

Comment: I'm OK with making the menu, but I'm having trouble with finding the operator or creating an operator that will allow me to switch to a custom brush or to a custom scene I have created.  If I wanted to make

Comment: Sorry for the above.  I know if sculpt mode that pressing x will do the following: bpy.ops.paint.brush_select(paint_mode='SCULPT', sculpt_tool='DRAW'.  I want to do something similiar, but want to be able to call a brush I have customized, for example "MY BRUSH 1" or "MY BRUSH 2."