# Shortcut Without Confirmation Dialog

Tags: interface, workflow, shortcut, parent

I'm new to Blender and I'm trying to add a shortcut to "Set Parent To: Object"

I want the shortcut to go to the action directly without the confirmation dialog, but I can't seem to get it working. Since the shortcut is keyed directly to the menu item "Object", logically it should go there directly without the pop up dialog, right? At least I expected it to work that way.

The UI suggests that <kbd>P</kbd> is now connected to the Object action, but this is not the case:

[image: Parent]

*I've removed all other bindings for* <kbd>P</kbd> *just to make sure*

Answer (score 3):

Preventing that this dialog appears seems not possible at the moment.

---

But you can define a 'custom operator' and 'create a shortcut' see: [Create Shortcuts for Particle Edit Brushes?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/9109/create-shortcuts-for-particle-edit-brushes)

For daily work I've converted this into an Add-on, which creates the shortcut automatically:

[image]

Install the Add-on via *File > User Preferences > Add-ons*. Once it's enabled you can press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for *Set Parent to Object* and also <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>P</kbd> for *Keep Transform* operation in *Object Mode*:

[image]

#### parent_shortcuts.py

```
bl_info = {
    "name": "Parenting Shortcuts",
    "description": "Parenting Shortcuts",
    "author": "poor",
    "version": (0, 0, 1),
    "blender": (2, 75, 0),
    "location": "3D View",
    "category": "3D View"
}

import bpy

# operators
class SetParentToObject(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.set_parent_object"
    bl_label = "Set Parent to Object"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type="OBJECT")
        return {'FINISHED'}

class SetParentKeepTransform(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Tooltip"""
    bl_idname = "object.set_parent_keep"
    bl_label = "Set Parent to Object (Keep Transform)"
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.ops.object.parent_set(type="OBJECT", keep_transform=True)
        return {'FINISHED'}


addon_keymaps = []

# register
def register():
    bpy.utils.register_class(SetParentToObject)
    bpy.utils.register_class(SetParentKeepTransform)

    # handle the keymap
    wm = bpy.context.window_manager
    kc = wm.keyconfigs.addon
    if kc:
        km = wm.keyconfigs.addon.keymaps.new(name='Object Mode', space_type='EMPTY')
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(SetParentToObject.bl_idname, type='P', value='PRESS', shift=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))
        kmi = km.keymap_items.new(SetParentKeepTransform.bl_idname, type='P', value='PRESS', alt=True, shift=True)
        addon_keymaps.append((km, kmi))

# unregister
def unregister():

    for km, kmi in addon_keymaps:
        km.keymap_items.remove(kmi)
    addon_keymaps.clear()

    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SetParentToObject)
    bpy.utils.unregister_class(SetParentKeepTransform)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    register()
```