# VSE snap a marker to the playhead?

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is any easy way to snap a marker to the playhead (green cursor)? (aside from zooming in really far and trying to position it as close as possible)

Answer (score 2):

You can set the Frame of your selected Marker to the current Frame via Python:

```
import bpy

s = bpy.data.scenes['Scene']

for m in s.timeline_markers:
    if m.select == True:
        m.frame = s.frame_current
```

Comment: Related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/3316/2843