# VSE markers hotkeys

Tags: video-sequence-editor

Is there a way to assign hotkeys to:
Jump to previous marker
Jump to next marker

In the menu marker/Jump to previous marker and Jump to next marker, letters t and J are underligned to indicate a hotkey possibility I'm gessing but I can get it to work. Thank you

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there a hot-key to jump between markers in the timeline?](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/28127/15140). Once there were default hotkeys for that, but they were removed. You should be able to set your own hotkey by right clicking on the menu>add shortcut.

Comment: @Maxime: you should mark questions as answered if you get the help you asked for. I also recommend, that you follow a VSE Tutorial like the great one from [Mikeycal Meyers](https://www.youtube.com/playlist?list=PLjyuVPBuorqIhlqZtoIvnAVQ3x18sNev4) to get started with Video Editing in Blender as most of your question will be answered there.

Comment: Hi. Will do. Many thanks for your answers I wasn't able to find elsewhere including Mikeycal's videos. All the best

Answer (score 1):

You can right-click on a Menu entry like "Jump to previous marker" and select "Add Shortcut" to set one.

In the "User Preferences" (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd>) in the "Input" Tab you can search for currently assigned Keyboard and Mouse Shortcuts and edit them or add new ones. But for adding new ones you'll need the RNA, therefore it's easier to directly right-click on a Menu entry you want to add a shortcut for as then Blender will add the RNA automatically.

[image: User Preferences Screenshot]